# How to connect when ssh broken pipe?

Tags: ssh

I have just modified a `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on a remote server. I added this to the bottom, but the subsystem was already defined so I removed the first two lines.

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group sftp
ChrootDirectory /home/sftp/%u
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

So, after removing the top lines I believe there was already a subsystem with some other code, so it might be like...

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
# other code
ChrootDirectory /home/sftp/%u
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

After this I `exit` from the ssh connection and now I get the error

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to 123.123.123.123 port 22: Broken pipe
```

When I try to login by ssh.

How can I fix this please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What lines did you add, all of them?

Comment: can you login via a direct command such as `ssh -tt thehosthere /bin/sh` ?

Comment: It looks like you must have restarted `sshd` process on the server after modifying `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, right? I can reproduce it here - after adding `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp` `sshd` daemon fails to start with error code 255.

Comment: Right, I did restart sshd. Is there a solution?

Comment: @thrig no same error.

Comment: If you don't have `sshd` daemon running on the remote server any
more there is nothing you can do. You have to use an alternative way
to reach the server such as `vpn` . Otherwise, you have to have
physical access to the machine.

Comment: Is it on a cloud provider? Often you're able to connect via a console.

Comment: You're going to need to look into the error logs. From there we can fix it.

Comment: You should check the syslogs on the ssh server. The sshd process should log something when it drops the connection.

Comment: The issue is this: `ChrootDirectory /home/sftp/%u`, and this `ForceCommand internal-sftp`. You removed the `Match Group sftp` line, so the chroot & forced command now apply to ALL connections. The only way to fix is if you have some method of access other than ssh.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick that's what I had to do in the end, luckily I was able to do that. Logging out to try the sftp connection instead of creating a new tab caused the headache - lesson learned. Thanks everyone.